# Sequelize model field that I did not add

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a user, role and their relation model, when I want to insert into the relation model I get this error:

```
  error: column "userUserId" of relation "roles_users_relationships" does not exist.
```

Can you help with this error?

(sorry if I wrote something wrong, this is my first question on )

This is how my model looks
Role model:

```
const Schema = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const table = sequelize.define(
    "roles", {
      role_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: sequelize.literal("uuid_generate_v4()"),
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      }
    }, {
      timestamps: false
    }
  );

  table.associate = function (models) {
    table.belongsToMany(models.users, {
      through: "roles_users_relationship",
      foreignKey: "role_id",
    });
  };
  return table;
};
```

Users model:

```
const Schema = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const table = sequelize.define(
    "users", {
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: sequelize.literal("uuid_generate_v4()"),
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
      }
    }, {
      timestamps: false
    }
  );

  table.associate = function (models) {
    table.belongsTo(models.roles, {
      through: "roles_users_relationship",
      foreignKey: "user_id",
    });
  };

  return table;
};
```

Roles Users relationship model:

```
const Schema = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const table = sequelize.define(
    "roles_users_relationship", {
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      role_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    }, {
      timestamps: false
    }
  );
  return table;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your through table you should add options in related table field:

```
references: {
  model: User,
  key: 'user_id'
}
```

Otherwise sequelize will do it automatically, like adding foreign key column in this way `tableNamePrimaryKeyColumn` in your case its 'userUserId'